# Making JavaScript Vars User Defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small little function, in Javascript / JQuery that adds a one of three classes to a div to colour code the background of the div which is depending on the date difference.

The date difference is worked out by PHP, which then echos / prints the value into a hidden field, which I when load into a loop with JQuery, my code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {                            
    var SetDateOne = 3;
    var SetDateTwo = 7;
    var SetDateThree = 8;

    $('.HideMe').each(function (i) {

       //This gets the hidden divs date diff.
       GetDateDiff = $("#Date" + i).html();

      if (GetDateDiff <= SetDateOne) {
        $('#' +i).addClass("RedLight");
      } else if (GetDateDiff <= SetDateTwo) {
        $('#' +i).addClass("YellowLight");
      } else if (GetDateDiff >= SetDateThree) {
        $('#' +i).addClass("GreenLight");
      }
   }); //End of .each function
});
```

So this all works, but I am trying to get these three dates set at the top to be user defined? I was thinking about session information? But I am not sure, but my thinking was to make a new table in my db, with just an id and date-set then set three dates within this table then load them into sessions but that would be with PHP, so not sure I could get that to load the session data into JavaScript.

Comment: Sessionstorage, localstorage, cookies & database are some options. Just get the item in any storage and assign it to the variable.

Comment: But can Javascript / JQuery read session information set by PHP?

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself how you want the data to persist. If its simply per browser then cookies works great. If its tied closely to a user and you want this to stick then a database may be more appropriate. Perhaps even utilizing a global cache on the server and key it by requester IP. There's a lot of different options each with pros and con's. I personally would with cookies for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see is you have a couple of options:

1. Like @morodeer has suggested you get the input values from the page. This implies that the user has to re-enter these values every time they visit the page.
2. Like you said you can use a Session to temporarily store data in the PHP session. This implies that the user will have to enter the dates once per session. See Example.
3. Use a JavaScript localdb in which you can store the data for extended periods of time. Assuming that the end user allows for localdb.
4. Use some kind of backend database to store your values. This will allow you to store data for extended period of time and perform data analysis. Providing that you have some way to uniquely identify users.

**PHP Session Example**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
$('.HideMe').each(function (i) {
    var SetDateOne = <?php echo $_SESSION['dateone']; ?>;
    ...
});
```

***EDIT:* PHP Session Example (With JavaScript Function)**

*JavaScript Function (js File)*

```
function doHideMe(dateOne, dateTwo, dateThree) {
    $('.HideMe').each(function (i) {
        var SetDateOne = dateOne;
        var SetDateTwo = dateTwo;
        var SetDateThree = dateThree;
        ...
    });
}
```

*Page Load (Included in individual pages)*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    doHideMe(<?php echo $_SESSION["dateOne"]; ?>, <?php echo $_SESSION["dateTwo"]; ?>, <?php echo $_SESSION["dateThree"]; ?>);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot to say that this function is inside an extenal .js file, has the colouring for the div happens on about five/six different pages. PHP will not work in that way, unless I add the code to each page - which would be a plain

Comment: Create a function where you can provide the PHP values as parameters which you call on page load

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure how? I am good with PHP but my javaScript is basic, how?